Create Call Data for function input using Nethereum
I want to call it a smart contract function. I am signing the transaction using Metamask so I need to create call data for the transaction.
I want to use Nethereum for creating the call data of the function. Any suggestions how can I achieve that?
I tried using the GetABIParamsEncoded msg and sent the transaction, but the transaction failed and no proper error was to be seen.
